Combinatorics problem from NMTC
I have tried at my best, but find it hard nut to crack. Actually, product form is so confusing. Any suggestions?

Find all quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ of positive integers with
$a \ge b \ge c \ge d$ such that $
\left(1+\dfrac{1}{a}\right) \left(1+\dfrac{1}{b}\right) \left(1+\dfrac{1}{c}\right) \left(1+\dfrac{1}{d}\right)=5$.


You aren't a new member, so you should know that [1] You shouldn't post a question without showing your efforts [2] You shouldn't write in imperative mood . ordering us to do your (probably) homework

As a seven-year user, you should not be unaware of using MathJax.

Sorry. This problem stings me, probably for this I forgot maintaining the community rules. And it's not my homework, I'm 63 years. Just love math.

Come on, guys, give him a break: he answered a question seven years ago and now he asks a question. Don't start bugging him about some formatting :-)

@trueblueanil  can you be more rude? Your comment is not needed. The same for you BoweiTang

If $a=b=c=d=2$ then the product is $5.0625$; if all of them are at least $2$ and not all equal then the product $\le \left(\frac32\right)^3\frac43\le 4.5$.
So at least one of $(a,b,c,d)$ must be $1$; hence $d=1$.
Hence we need to find all positive integer triples $(a,b,c)$, $a\ge b \ge c$, such that
$$
(*)=\left(1+\frac1a\right)\left(1+\frac1b\right)\left(1+\frac1c\right)=\frac52.
$$
If $c\ge 3$, then $(*)\le (4/3)^3<2.5$, so $c=1$ or $c=2$.
Case $c=1$: we need to find $a\ge b$ such that
$$
(**)=\left(1+\frac1a\right)\left(1+\frac1b\right)=\frac54.
$$
If $b\ge 9$, then $(**)\ge (10/9)^2=1.23...<5/4$, so $b\le 8$.
Also $(**)$ is equivalent to $4a+4b+4=ab$, i.e.
$$
a=\frac{4b+4}{b-4}.
$$
One can see that only $b=5,6,8$ result in an integer $a$,
Case $c=2$: we need to find $a\ge b$ such that
$$
(***)=\left(1+\frac1a\right)\left(1+\frac1b\right)=\frac53.
$$
If $b\ge 4$, then $(**)\ge (5/4)^2=1.5625...<5/3$, so $b\le 3$, which gives integer solution for $b=2$ and $b=3$.
So the only solutions are:
\begin{align}
(24,5,1,1)\quad
(14,6,1,1)\quad
(9,8,1,1)\quad
(9,2,2,1)\quad
(4,3,2,1).
\end{align}

In your case $c=1$, you (obviously) missed $b=5$, and hence one more possible solution...

Thanks, corrected!

Thanks a lot. But some inequality sign  problem. (**) <= (10/9)^2.
